# VBA Excel: Input Box Date Specified Yet Data for All Dates is Being Generated

Tags: vba, date, excel, inputbox

I have a button_click macro that is to run a lengthy set of VBA code to create and/or update a daily report based on the date entered in an input box, a monthly report sheet with just the daily totals, and an unmatched report sheet for the UIDs that do not match between the two sheets containing the original data. For most dates this works as it should. However, when the date "7/11/2014" is entered in numeric format it pulls all of the dates from 7/11/2014 to the end of the available dates in both sheets. However, if I enter the date as "July 11,2014" the script runs as it should.

Is there a reason WHY 7/11/2014 (7/11, or 7/11/14) would pull in data from 7/11/14 forward, rather than just data specifically related to 7/11/14? My code is very lengthy and I'm not sure if it is an Excel issue with dates or if I have an issue in my code, and if so where.

I can share code if necessary but as I said, I'm not sure where the issue is located.

Thanks,
TSC

Comment: Can you check the cell value of the date that is used for the input?  Is it text or is it actually a date value.  If its a value, can you post the code that loads the date?

Comment: The user manually enters the cell value for the date and I have it setup as a variable. It then is converted into 3 different date formats to create the report name and match with each of the worksheets with original data.

Comment: I figured out the "error" it was way down in my code. In order to find the "end" row for the set of data I was relying on either the next date or the date after it to have data in one of the worksheets. If neither existed, then I set the code to go to the last row of the sheet. In this case, there was no data in that sheet for 20140712 nor 20140713, which meant that the end range was to the end of the sheet. After taking a break, I came back and think I fixed the issue. (Will show code below just for reference.)

Answer (score 0):

Original code

```
    ' if the requested date exists in wksKEY column A, then proceed.
If dtExists(sKeyDate, wksKEY, "A:A") Then
        ' nFDtRow = the first row in wksKEY with the requested date, which is stored in
        ' wksGDR A5 using Keystone_Data date format of YYYYMMDD
    nFDtRow = MatchUID(wksGDR, wksKEY, "A5", "A1:A" & lKeyLastRow)
        ' nLDtRow = last row in wksKEY with specified date; stored in wksGDR A6 as YYYYMMDD
    nLDtRow = MatchUID(wksGDR, wksKEY, "A6", "A1:A" & lKeyLastRow) - 1
        ' if the last date row is less than the first date row, then...
    If nLDtRow < nFDtRow Then
            ' wksGDR A6 = the date in A5 + 2 (i.e. if 20140102 is the date selected and 20140103
            ' is not in wksKEY, then wksGDR A6 = 20140104)
        wksGDR.Range("A6").Value = wksGDR.Range("A5").Value + 2
            ' if there is not a match in wksKEY for the value in wksGDR A6, IsError will equal True.
            ' if there is not an error, hence the match search = True, then ...
        If Not MatchUID(wksGDR, wksKEY, "A6", "A1:A" & lKeyLastRow) = 0 Then
                ' nLDtRow = the first row with the value in wksGDR A6 - 1 to equal the last row with the
                ' desired date
            nLDtRow = MatchUID(wksGDR, wksKEY, "A6", "A1:A" & lKeyLastRow) - 1
        Else
                ' Otherwise, if there is an error, nLDtRow equals the last row in wksKEY
            nLDtRow = lKeyLastRow
        End If
    End If
        ' nCtDtRow = the total count of matching date rows in wksKEY
    nCtDtRow = (nLDtRow - nFDtRow) + 1
        ' review each row with i doing the count and j representing the actual row number
    For i = 1 To nCtDtRow
            ' lDRNewRow = the row number where a new row can be added
        lDRNewRow = lDRRowEnd + i
            ' j = the first date row # + i (counting from 1 to the total #) - 1 to get the proper
            ' row #
        j = nFDtRow + (i - 1)
            ' If current UID does not already exist in a Daily_Report or the Unmatched_Report, then...
        If StopDupeUIDs(wksKEY, "AM" & j, lKeyLastRow) = True Then
                ' Verify that there is no match between the current UID and one already in wksDR
            If MatchUID(wksKEY, wksDR, "AM" & j, "P3:P" & lDRRowEnd) = "0" Then
                    ' enter wksKEY UID into wksDR column P
                wksDR.Range("P" & lDRNewRow).Value = wksKEY.Range("AM" & j)
            End If
        Else
                ' Otherwise, if the requested UID already exists in another sheet, update column R and color it bright green
            If UpdateUID(wksKEY, "AM" & j, lKeyLastRow) <> "" Then
                wksGDR.Range("A7").Value = UpdateUID(wksKEY, "AM" & j, lKeyLastRow)
                sTempWS = Left(wksGDR.Range("A7").Value, InStr(1, wksGDR.Range("A7"), Chr(124), vbTextCompare) - 1)
                lTempCell = Right(wksGDR.Range("A7").Value, Len(wksGDR.Range("A7")) - InStr(1, wksGDR.Range("A7"), Chr(124), vbTextCompare))
                Worksheets(sTempWS).Range("R" & lTempCell).Value = j
                Worksheets(sTempWS).Range("R" & lTempCell).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)
                Call ckQty(Worksheets(sTempWS), lTempCell, lTempCell)
            End If
                wksGDR.Range("A7").Value = ""
        End If
    Next i
Else
    ' otherwise, if the requested date does not exist in wksKEY column A, exit this subroutine.
    Exit Sub
End If
```

To correct the issue, and hopefully make it more versatile, I removed the 'If nLDtRow < nfDtRow Then...' statement and replaced it with

```
     ' wksGDR A6 = the number of times sKeyDate exists within wksKEY column A
    wksGDR.Range("A6").Value = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(wksKEY.Range("A1:A" & lKeyLastRow), sKeyDate)
        ' wksGDR A7 = nFDtRow + wksGDR A6
    wksGDR.Range("A7").Value = nFDtRow + wksGDR.Range("A6").Value
       ' nLDtRow = wksGDR A7
    nLDtRow = wksGDR.Range("A7").Value
```

I also updated nCtDtRow to `nCtDtRow = wksGDR.Range("A6").Value` rather than trying to recalculate it.

I've been learning VBA (it has been more than a decade since I took VB in school or really used it for anything) as I've gone along with this project.